# HTML tags in marker, Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

In my MVC5 project, using Leaflet, I am using the following code to display markers which are clickable and display further information such as addresses or phones in an outside .
It works fine until the addresses start containing html code (`<br/>, <b>`, etc..).

```
@foreach(var location in Model.Data.OfficeLocations)
        {
            <text>
                var marker = L.marker(
                                L.latLng(
                                    parseFloat(@location.Latitude),
                                    parseFloat(@location.Longitude)
                                ),
                                 { 
                                    name: '@(location.Tooltip)',                                   
                                    address: '@(location.Address)',
                                    phone: '@(location.Phone)'
                                }
                            ).addTo(mymap).on('click', displayInfo);

                marker.bindPopup("@location.Tooltip");   

                </text>
        }       

        function displayInfo(e) {
            document.getElementById("information").innerText = this.options.Address;
        }
```

I have a 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token' error for the address variable in my browser:

```
{ 
                                    name: 'my location',                                   
                                    address: 'my address&lt;br /&gt;
LAX &lt;br /&gt;
USA',
                                    phone: '+1 111 111 111'
                                }
```

How can i store html code in my marker in order to be later reused by my `displayInfo` JS function?

Comment: Although kudos for this creative approach, I'd suggest that you make your data available as JSON and download it using either `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` from the client to add it to your map. Create an endpoint from to retrieve the data instead of printing JavaScript code in your document.

Comment: Thank you @EmielZuurbier. I wanted to take this approach to avoid having to call my data twice. I will see how to return a json which contains what I need and then displayed it in my outside div.

Comment: Does `address` contain line breaks (`\n`s and/or `\r`s)? Strings in javascript are supposed to be single-line only, so you either should escape newlines, or use template literal strings (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `innerText` with `innerHtml` if you want html to be interpreted.

Comment: Good point. My issue is really at the storage of the value in the marker itself. I have edited my answer to show the type of error.